# R: Added import(data.table) to NAMESPACE automatically using devtools

Tags: r, namespaces, devtools

How do I correctly add `import(data.table)` to the `NAMESPACE` file automatically using `devtools`?

Generally if my packages use `data.table` I just write it in manually, but then I can't use `@export` and `devtools::document` to create the `NAMESPACE` file properly, as it either overwrites the addition I've made, or doesn't update the file at all.

Plus, it says not edit it manually...

Thanks

---

Sample `package/R/function.R` code

```
#' @export
#' @import data.table
test_data_table = function(dt) {
  dt[, a := 3]
}
```

---

Call example

```
> test_data_table
function(dt) {
  dt[, a := 3]
}
<environment: namespace:package>

> test_data_table(dt)
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in `[.data.frame`(x, i, j) : could not find function ":="
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably shouldn't use `import(*)` at all, unless you *really* need every exported object from a package. Instead, use `importFrom(pkg, obj1, obj2, ...)` to import only those objects you need.

From the *Writing R Extensions* manual, S1.5.1:

> Using `importFrom` selectively rather than `import` is good practice and recommended notably when importing from packages with more than a dozen exports.

Nonetheless, if you *do* need to import everything, use `#' @import data.table`.

Comment: `data.table` is actually one of the few packages where I would `import` everything.

Comment: Well I guess the problem is that it's the syntax. Am I to understand I use `importFrom(data.table, data.table.[)`?

Comment: @AkhilNair The method is `[.data.table`, but you can't import it because it is not exported. I doubt you can import from data.table selectively and still use data.table itself. There are some functions you can import selectively from data.table, but AFAIK not those creating the core functionality.

Comment: @Roland, I thought that all this implies it should be done like the snippet I added to the OP.  If so, with that code I'm still getting the `could not find :=` error.

Comment: @Roland Oops - Sorry, that was stupid. On fixing that I still see an error though (clarification in OP)

Comment: @AkhilNair Is data.table declared as Imports in the DESCRIPTION file? Have you reroxygenized?

Comment: @Roland, That was my main mistake. Thank you!