# data.table in R: Why can't data.table::`:=`() be called?

Tags: r, data.table

Use `DT = data.table(type=rep(c("b","a"),each=2), value=1:4)` to create the following data.table:

```
   type value
1:    b     1
2:    b     2
3:    a     3
4:    a     4
```

The code `` DT[, `:=`(text=max(value)), by=type] `` works well:

```
   type value test
1:    b     1    2
2:    b     2    2
3:    a     3    4
4:    a     4    4
```

Same code (except for the `data.table::` calling part) `` DT[, data.table::`:=`(text=max(value)), by=type] `` doesn't work and returns the following error:

```
Error in data.table::`:=`(text = max(value)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. 
  Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, 
  once only and in particular ways. 
  See help(":=").
```

Can someone tell me why I can't call the `:=` function like `` data.table::`:=`() `` but can call other functions like `data.table` as `data.table::data.table`?

Please help me, as I want to use `` data.table::`:=`() `` in my package.

Many thanks ahead!

Comment: What Kind of language is it?

Comment: It's R language. Let me edit the question title. Here is my environment:R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.3

Comment: Here is my environment:

package ‘data.table’ version 1.10.4

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)

Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0 (64-bit)

Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.3

Comment: just curious, why do you want to call it that way?

Comment: Here is where this problem comes: I am developing a package heavily using `data.table`. In DESCRIPTION file, I write `Depends: data.table`. In NAMESPACE file, I write `import(data.table)`. When I use `devtools::test()` to test my function, the error same with this problem comes up, I tried both the ``data.table::`:=`()`` way and the `:=` way, both two ways lead to the error, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: `:=` isn't a function so you can't call it with namespace prefix `datatable::`

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much! Could you tell me if `:=` isn't a function, which type it should belong to? How could I tell other components in `data.table` package which can't be called in this way? Many thanks. @s.brunel

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888820/r-added-importdata-table-to-namespace-automatically-using-devtools